# MVVMCross CrossUI.Droid Hello World

Tags: mvvmcross, monodroid.dialog

I am Trying to use MVVMCross CrossUI Droid on its own for a quick test from [here](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/v3.1/CrossUI/CrossUI.Droid)

In VS2013 I have created a new Android Application, added CrossUI and changed the target framework on CrossUI.Core (ticked all + 4.5+) to compile CrossUI.Core and CrossUI.Dialog.

The [link](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/CrossUI/CrossUI.Droid/DialogLayouts) for layouts in the ReadMe paragraph gives a 404 error.

"... and add these layouts to your Resources/Layout folder: Android.Dialog Layouts Expect an easier way to manage this after Mono for Android 4.4 is released."

I assume they will still be needed in layout as I get a missing layout error on run.

I have also "tried" to add some dialog layouts from old project that can be found [here](https://github.com/kevinmcmahon/MonoDroid.Dialog/tree/lastsnapshot/DialogSampleApp/)

using code (I am trying to piece this together but could be way off hence this help request) -

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        DroidResources.Initialize(typeof(Resource.Layout));

        var Root = new RootElement()
        {
            new Section("Test Section")
                {
                    new StringElement("Test:"),
                }
        };

        var da = new DialogAdapter(this, Root);
        var lv = new ListView(this) { Adapter = da };

        SetContentView(lv);
    }
```

still get -

```
02-28 10:56:32.639 E/Android.Dialog( 2382): LoadLayout failed: Could not find resource field dialog_multiline_labelfieldbelow
02-28 10:56:32.639 E/Android.Dialog( 2382): LoadStringElementLayout: Failed to load resource: dialog_multiline_labelfieldbelow
```

Could someone show / point me to a / some working sample(s) for getting CrossUI.Droid Dialogs rendering on screen?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you no longer need to include the resources manually when using MvvmCross.

The easiest starting point for this are probably:

- [The MvvmCross DialogExamples app](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/tree/master/DialogExamples)
- The N+1 video - see N=23 in this [blog](http://mvvmcross.blogspot.com) - including blog and code links

Comment: Thanks Stuart, Would you consider updating the Readme file(s) for the CrossUI files to point users to this information?